# Using this slice my object

Tags: c++, object-slicing

I have some difficulties using `this`, it seems to slice my derived class. This example will help me to explain my problem.

```
class A 
{
    A() {
        OtherClass(*this);
    }

    virtual doSomething() = 0;
}

class B : public A
{
    B() : A() {}

    doSomething() override {
        std::cout << "Hi!" << std::endl;
    }
}

class OtherClass() 
{
    OtherClass(A &a) {
        a.doSomething();
    }
}
```

After some investigation it seems like that using `*this` slice the class `B`. And then `OtherClass` will call a pure virtual method on `A`. I'm wrong? Should I make the `OtherClass(*this)`, after the Initialization of the `B` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A`'s constructor invokes `OtherClass`'s constructor, which invokes `A`'s pure virtual method.

Unfortunately, since `A`'s subclass, which implements this virtual method, hasn't been constructed yet, the result is undefined behavior.

Remember: superclasses get constructed before subclasses. Before `B` can get constructed (and thus implement the pure virtual method), it's superclass, `A`, needs to get constructed fully. As a part of that process, of course, `A`'s constructor gets invoked.

Comment: 'subclasses get constructed before superclasses'.  Is that right? Base (super) classes will be constructed before derived (sub) classes.

Answer (score 2):

Thus is not a slicing issue.

In a constructor/destructor, virtual methods are not called virtually.

The rational is that the object has not been fully constructed, or has been partially destroyed.  The `this` pointer does not point at any derived class, only to the class currently being constructed/destructed (in this case, `A`).

Comment: Actually in `OtherClass` `A::doSomething` *will* be called virtually. But since the objects dynamic type hasn't been adjusted yet (the c'tor of `A` isn't finished and the object point's to `A`s vtable), a pure virtual is called.

Comment: @StoryTeller: `this->doSomething()` in constructor/destructor will be equivalent to `A::doSomething()` (so pure virtual call in OP's case) instead of `B::doSomething()`, (even if compiler choose to pass by *"modified"* vtable for that (think about diamond hierarchy)).

Comment: But this isn't `this->doSomething()`. It's `anotherObj->doSoemthing()`.